# How to export a Dash Plotly app to a single HTML page

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a simple Dash Plotly app that is taken from the Dash tutorial and contains some styles, Dash Core Components including a slide bar and a Plotly figure.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph-with-slider'),
    dcc.Slider(
        df['year'].min(),
        df['year'].max(),
        step=None,
        value=df['year'].min(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['year'].unique()},
        id='year-slider'
    )
])


@app.callback(
    Output('graph-with-slider', 'figure'),
    Input('year-slider', 'value'))
def update_figure(selected_year):
    filtered_df = df[df.year == selected_year]

    fig = px.scatter(filtered_df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
                     size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
                     log_x=True, size_max=55)

    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I would like to export this entire Dash app including the style, html components and the interactive figure to a single html page so that I can easily share with my colleagues.

I am pretty new to Dash and Plotly. How can I achieve it?

Comment: you can't put in one HTML because it needs web server - it uses JavaScript which sends data to server (Flask) and it sends back results. And this also need to install Python with Dash

Comment: if colleagues will install Python with Dash then you can easily share this file.

Comment: maybe you should use servers like [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) which use `Juputer` to make calculation and display plots with some widgets, etc.

Comment: Try this:[https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/#html-export-in-dash](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/#html-export-in-dash)

Comment: @r-beginners this only exports the figure but not the html component rendered by Dash Components.

Comment: Have you actually pressed the download button on this page? Pressing this will save the plotly_graph.html locally. Clicking it will display it in your default browser.